# Why does NIntegrate give inconsistent results for this integral?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a rather complicated $2$-dimensional integral for which I would like to collect numerical data for different values of a parameter $\epsilon$. Just looking at the structure of the integral (see code below), it is clear that the result should be symmetric for $\epsilon \leftrightarrow -\epsilon$, when $| \epsilon | \gg 1$. As a first check that I did not make a mistake while typing my integrand, here are two plots for $\epsilon = +100$ (left) and $\epsilon = -100$ (right):

[image]

So far so good, the approximate symmetry mentioned above seems to be respected. Note that the function is smooth on the line $\tau_3 = \tau_4$, but Mathematica sees it as `Indeterminate`. When I integrate, I get completely different results, namely $0.0001551170491$ for $\epsilon = +100$ and $1356.703732$ for $\epsilon = -100$! I tried changing the methods (`GlobalAdaptive`, `GaussKronrodRule`, `MultidimensionalRule`, `Trapezoidal`,...), tweaking the precision and accuracy parameters, and excluding the line $\tau_3 = \tau_4$ without success. Note that the results are $-0.01746598795$ for $\epsilon = +100$ and $1356.682697$ for $\epsilon = -100$ when excluding $\tau_3 = \tau_4$.

Since the plots of the integrands came out correctly, I thought maybe that this has something to do with the sampling points. Here is the way it is sampled with `GlobalAdaptive` (left: $\epsilon = +100$, right: $\epsilon=-100$):

[image]

To me it looks like as if the case $\epsilon=+100$ had more trouble converging, but that is expected since the output is much smaller, as more points are needed for reaching the desired precision/accuracy (right?). Thus I guess the problem is elsewhere.

Any idea what is going wrong here, and how to fix it? Here is the code I used:

```
AG = 4;
PG = 4;
WP = 10;

x2 = Sqrt[ϵ^2];
x12 := Sqrt[(1 - ϵ)^2];
x13[τ3_] := Sqrt[1^2 + τ3^2];
x14[τ4_] := Sqrt[1^2 + τ4^2];
x23[τ3_] := Sqrt[ϵ^2 + τ3^2];
x24[τ4_] := Sqrt[ϵ^2 + τ4^2];
x34[τ3_, τ4_] := Sqrt[(τ3 - τ4)^2];

R[τ3_, τ4_] := (x12^2 x34[τ3, τ4]^2)/(x13[τ3]^2 x24[τ4]^2);
S[τ3_, τ4_] := (x14[τ4]^2 x23[τ3]^2)/(x13[τ3]^2 x24[τ4]^2);

a[τ3_, τ4_] := 1/4 Sqrt[4*R[τ3, τ4]*S[τ3, τ4] - (1 - R[τ3, τ4] - S[τ3, τ4])^2];
f[τ3_, τ4_] := I Sqrt[-((1 - R[τ3, τ4] - S[τ3, τ4] - 4 I*a[τ3, τ4])/(1 - R[τ3, τ4] - S[τ3, τ4] + 4 I*a[τ3, τ4]))];
ϕ[τ3_, τ4_] := 1/a[τ3, τ4] Im[PolyLog[2, f[τ3, τ4] Sqrt[R[τ3, τ4]/S[τ3, τ4]]] + Log[Sqrt[R[τ3, τ4]/S[τ3, τ4]]]*Log[1 - f[τ3, τ4] Sqrt[R[τ3, τ4]/S[τ3, τ4]]]];
X1234[τ3_, τ4_] := 1/(16 π^2) 1/((2 π)^4 x13[τ3]^2 x24[τ4]^2) ϕ[τ3, τ4];

integrand[τ3_, τ4_] := Evaluate@Simplify[10^8*x2 1/(x13[τ3]^2 x24[τ4]^2) (x12^2 x34[τ3, τ4]^2 - x14[τ4]^2 x23[τ3]^2 + x13[τ3]^2 x24[τ4]^2) X1234[τ3, τ4]];

NIntegrate[Chop[integrand[τ3, τ4]] /. ϵ -> 100, {τ3, -∞, ∞}, {τ4, -∞, ∞}, Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule"}, AccuracyGoal -> AG, PrecisionGoal -> PG, WorkingPrecision -> WP]
NIntegrate[Chop[integrand[τ3, τ4]] /. ϵ -> -100, {τ3, -∞, ∞}, {τ4, -∞, ∞}, Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule"}, AccuracyGoal -> AG, PrecisionGoal -> PG, WorkingPrecision -> WP]
```

Comment: The command `Plot3D[integrand[\[Tau]3, \[Tau]4], {\[Tau]3, 1, 5}, {\[Tau]4, 1, 5}]` produces an error "Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression (0. +0. I) ComplexInfinity encountered." and an empty plot.

Comment: @user64494 Did you specify a $\epsilon$ though?

Comment: @user64494 I have the same error messages, but the plot is not empty when I run e.g. `Plot3D[Chop[integrand[\[Tau]3, \[Tau]4]] /. \[Epsilon] -> 100, {\[Tau]3, 1, 5}, {\[Tau]4, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`. Note that without chopping the integrand has slight imaginary parts, which is maybe why you plot comes out empty.

Comment: You are right. I missed `\[Epsilon] = 100;` before the plot command.

Comment: The result of the executed  code `\[Epsilon] = -100; Plot3D[
 integrand[\[Tau]3, \[Tau]4], {\[Tau]3, -100, 100}, {\[Tau]4, -100, 
  100}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints->50] ` shows a singularity at the origin. The same issue with ``\[Epsilon] = 100;` instead of.

Comment: @user64494 Try changing the limits of the plot to $-1$ and $+1$. I don't think that it is singular at the origin.

Comment: You wrote "it is clear that the result should be symmetric ", but I don't see it, executing `Plot3D[integrand[x, y] /. \[Epsilon] -> 
    100 - integrand[x, y] /. \[Epsilon] -> -100, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}]`.

Comment: @user64494 I meant *approximately* symmetric. The agreement between integrand($\tau_3$,$\tau_4$,$\epsilon$) and integrand($\tau_3$,$\tau_4$,$-\epsilon$) reaches $\sim 5$ significant digits for $\left| \epsilon \right| \sim 10000$ (it depends weakly on the values of $\tau$ you input). The two plots in the OP show the symmetry clearly, and it is easy to see it in the definitions since there are only $\epsilon^2$ and $(1-\epsilon)^2$ appearing.

Comment: Unfortunately, `NIntegrate[
 integrand[x, y] /. \[Epsilon] -> 
    100 - integrand[x, y] /. \[Epsilon] -> -100, {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 2, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]` performs `-1476.3646735132770123` without any error massage.

Comment: @user64494 Yeah, that is precisely the point of my post. This is a non-sensical result. I mean, look at the plots of the OP. Clearly this can't be right.

Comment: Sorry, I prefer arguments over your  "appoximate symmetry".All the best.

Comment: @user64494 I think I gave you plenty of arguments, but I could be wrong. I will check my arguments thoroughly again.

Comment: Here is a simpler example of such kind: `NIntegrate[10/(1 +( x + y )^2- Sin[x*y]), {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}]` produces `15585.9`  and  `NIntegrate[10/(1 +( x + y)^2 + Sin[x*y]), {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}]` performs `4890.17`  though the plots are "approximate symmetric".

Comment: Why use `WP = 10`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No reason, I usually use $20$ but tweaked it to see if it was changing something. I guess user64494 is right, my assumption might be wrong in the first place. Still investigating that.